# How to execute powershell(x86) with schedule task?

Tags: powershell, scripting, x86, taskscheduler

I am automating send mail with outlook. My script make var outlook with .application:

```
$Global:outlook = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
```

My problem is about Task Schedule, Outlook is x86 and only work in ISE(x86) so I need make Task Schedule invoke powershell(x86). How can I do?

Example about task schedule:

```
PowerShell -File "C:\Users\Victor\Script.ps1"
```

thanks for the help and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call the x86 version of Powershell using
`%SystemRoot%\syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`

Comment: yes, I use literal but i expect the path SystemRoot work. Maybe i change -File for -Command. But this is well. Thanks